# AngularJS : Scope issue in $http success callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller, angularjs-factory

I'm using PHP to get data into my factory, which shows correctly in the success callback function within the controller. However, even after assigning the returned data to $scope.customers, it's not there if I do a console.log($scope.customers) after the callbacks, and my view's [ng-repeat] isn't picking it up either.

Any idea why the scope of my data would be restricted to just inside the success callback if I'm assigning the returned data to my $scope object?

```
var customersController = function($scope, customersFactory) {
  $scope.customers = [];
  customersFactory.getAllData()
    .success(function(customers) {
      $scope.customers = customers;
      console.log($scope.customers); // Object with correct data
    }); // No errors so only showing happy path
  console.log($scope.customers); // empty []
};
customersModule.controller('customersController', ['$scope', 'customersFactory', customersController]);
```

Comment: The callback is called after...

Comment: This is true, and I should have focused my question more with where I mentioned my view's [ng-repeat] not picking up the data, when the returned data is assigned to $scope inside the success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$http functions happen asynchronously. Thus, calling console.log after the `customersFactory.getAllData` will always be empty.

`console.log($scope.customers); // Object with correct data`

is actually happening AFTER

`console.log($scope.customers); // empty []`

You can trust the success callback to set `$scope.customers` correctly, you just need your site to understand that it will happen later. If you NEED scope.customers to be populated before the view loads, consider using a resolve on the controller.

Comment: I thought the view with ng-repeat was tied to the controller, so when the controller is updated, the view is updated as well. I was willing to make the assumption the success() is fine by itself, but the view not updating is what was confusing me when the ng-repeat wasn't showing the data either.

Comment: You were right in that the data 'is' in the success, and to just trust and go with that, and that became the basis for my research/debugging. This led to my finding the issue which was in how I was referencing the data. $scope.customers = customers.goodCustomers; // The view had nothing to show because the returned customers array had a sub-array of types of customers. I appreciated delving into and trying out the routing resolve, however, as well as learning about $scope.apply() - obviously for which neither applied, but was a good learning experience.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't

```
console.log($scope.customers); // empty []
```

executing before

```
console.log($scope.customers); // Object with correct data
```

?

The second one is in a success() callback so it could execute much later than the first one.

Comment: The success() is executing later, correct. Which is what I believe @Fourth is referring to.